# How to Handle State Being Re-Initialized on API Call Response?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have the below functional component in a simple MERN application. My problem is the `output` state is reset to `["Let's run a test..."]` when the API call returns, so I always only get an array of that and the last output, instead of an array of all outputs.

`output` state looks like: `["Let's run a test..."]` on refresh the page, `["Running tests...]` on  `testRunner` click, and `["Let's run a test...", "test result"]` on `testRunner` response. I'm expecting `["Running tests...", "test result 1", "test result 2", ...]` on `testRunner` response. Is `useEffect` having some effect I'm not aware of? How should I be doing this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import apis from '../api/index';
import Header from './Header';
import Output from './Output';

function App() {

  const [output, setOutput] = useState([]);

  const testRunner = async () => {

    setOutput(["Running tests..."]);

    for (const item of selectedItemTypes) {
      const payload = { 
        "itemPrefix": item,
        "testFunction": selectedTestFunctions
      };
      await apis.testRunner(payload).then(res => {
        setOutput([...output, `${item}: ${res.data.result}`]);
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    async function initialize() {
      setOutput(["Let's run a test..."]);
    }

    initialize();

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header 
        testRunner={testRunner}
      />
      <Container>
        <ChildContainer>
          <TitleDiv>Select Test Function(s)</TitleDiv>
          <TestPicker />
        </ChildContainer>
        <ChildContainer>
          <TitleDiv>Select Item Type(s)</TitleDiv>
          <ItemTypePicker />
        </ChildContainer>
        <ChildContainer>
          <TitleDiv>Output</TitleDiv>
          <Output
            output={output}
           />
        </ChildContainer>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your testRunner function doesn't look like it is ever called.

Comment: It is called via a button in a Header component. I'll add that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the old output value to setOutput in order to get the result you want. So in your testRunner function you'll do something like this.

```
await apis.testRunner(payload).then(res => {
    setOutput((output) => [...output, `${item}: ${res.data.result}`]);
});
```

[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous. On testRunner click you set the output state to ["Running tests..."]. But output value was not updated on setOutput([...output,`${item}: ${res.data.result}`]);

setState can take an argument as a function. In the first argument of passed function, you will get the previous state.

Solution -

```
setOutput((prevOutput)=>[...prevOutput, `${item}: ${res.data.result}`]);
```